# non-exhaustive pattern error haskell

Tags: string, haskell, matching

I'm trying to parse an input from user into my datatype:

```
type Var = String
data FProp = V Var
            | No FProp
            | Y FProp FProp
            | O FProp FProp
            | Si FProp FProp
            | Sii FProp FProp deriving Read
```

using this function, by pattern matching:

```
f:: [String] -> FProp
f("(":"S":"i":"(":xs) = (Si (let x = fst (span (/= ")") xs) in f x) (let y = snd (span (/= ")") xs) in f y))
f("(":"Y":"(":xs) = (Y (let x = fst (span (/= ")") xs) in f x) (let y = snd (span (/= ")") xs) in f y))
f("(":"S":"i":"i":"(":xs) = (Sii (let x = fst (span (/= ")") xs) in f x) (let y = snd (span (/= ")") xs) in f y))
f("(":"O":"(":xs) = (O (let x = fst (span (/= ")") xs) in f x) (let y = snd (span (/= ")") xs) in f y))
f("(":"N":"O":"(":xs) = (No (f xs))
f ("(":"V":"(":xs) = (V(head xs))
```

The input would look like: "(Si (V(q)) (No (V(p))))" (equivalent to the formula: q -> ¬p).

It seemed like everything went fine, when I got this error: **Non-exhaustive patterns in function f**
¿Can I get some help in order to solve this?
I think it might have to do with the way I defined the last recursive case (the one for V).

Comment: You can compile with `-Wall` and it will show which patterns are missing, but that being said, you make this function terribly complex. I would advice to use a *push down automaton*, so with a list (as stack) as accumulator.

Comment: Furthermore this will not always work since the `span (/= ")")` will cut off from the moment it finds a closing bracket, but if you write `"foo(bar(qux))"`, then it will thus find `bar(qux` as inner content.

Comment: can you be more specific with the acumulator idea? I'm actually a bit lost on how to implement it

Comment: You can implement a stack as a list where the head of the list is the top of the stack.  You push with `cons` and pop with `head`.  Or you can write a recursive-descent parser and use the built-in stack.

Comment: But you seem to be having a lot of problems with a part of this assignment that is kind of ancillary to the main point you’re supposed to be learning. You might find it valuable to come back and write a parser later by hand, but maybe you want to take the easy way out here.

Answer (score 3):

The function you implemented is partial, not all cases are covered. You need to add a catch-all case and return an error.
To be able to do that, the function should return a type that allows modelling parsing failures (like `Either Error FProp`).

In my opinion you can create a much better parser with the [parsec library](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsec). There are also many [great tutorials](http://jakewheat.github.io/intro_to_parsing/) you might want to investigate.

Comment: The problema is, I cannot use the parsec library, because I'm only allowed to use prelude functions

Comment: Right, I see, may I suggest this one, then?
Error = String
`f :: [String] -> Either Error FProp`
`...`
`f _ = Left "Unrecognized expression"`